# FPC Clipboard Viewer Handler kills Ctrl-X functionality in Articulate Storyline

Tags: clipboard, lazarus, freepascal

I have implemented an application displaying the Windows clipboard contents, it follows this scheme to insert itself into the chain of viewers and handling the WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD message:

https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Clipboard#Getting_notified_of_changes

If my program, or this sample program, runs in the background, the Ctrl-X and Shift-Del (cut text) keyboard shortcuts do not work properly in Articulate Storyline any more. Pressing any of those two key combinations puts the highlighted text into the clipboard, but doesn't delete it from the Storyline input, I have to press "Del" to get rid of it in Storyline.

There seems to be an incompatibility between Storyline and my code, which is odd, because my code is just a passive viewer which should not have any adverse effect on any software running.

This behaviour appears only in Storyline (as far as I can tell, I tried several other programs, and found both Strg-X and Shift-Del working OK), but it is caused by my code, since if I end my program Storyline works OK at once, and if I start my code the problem appears right away.

Other programs, like NirSofts clipboard viewer (InsideKeyboard.exe), which suspectedly use the same technique to monitor the clipboard do not have adverse affects on Storyline.

Anyone having an idea, why my (short, simple and harmless) code can cause such adverse effects just in Articulate Storyline?

Comment: The only thing I notice in the sample in the documentation is that TForm1.WMChangeCBChain misses to set the result, it should return 0. It might not effect the behavior you observe though.

Comment: I already noticed the missing function result, and changed the code to return 0, but this did not change anything.